# Tkinter and threads

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

So, what I am trying to do is to create a tkinter window and then deplace it across the screen without reopening the GUI. The first problem I am facing is that the threading doesn't seem to work. The program chooses to only run the deplacewindow function and ignoring the code below the thread.start line. Is it possible to fix this? Or is there a better way to displace a tkinter window across the screen?

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time,threading

root = tk.Tk() # create a Tk root window

w = 200 # width for the Tk root
h = 200 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
sw = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
sh = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window to appear on the
# bottom right of the screen
x = sw - w - 20
y = sh - h - 80
print (sw,"-",w,"    ",sh,"-",h)
print (x,y)


# set the dimensions of the screen 
# and where it is placed
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

def mainloop():
    global root
    root.mainloop() # starts the mainloop
def deplaceWindow():
    global root,x
    print ("Starting loop")
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        x-=10
        print (x)
        #root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
print ("starting thread")
threading.Thread(target=deplaceWindow()).start()
print ("starting mainloop")
mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need threads for such a program. Plus, tkinter isn't thread safe. You can't reliably access GUI elements from any thread other than the one where they were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you want is a *timer* event. TkInter uses the **after** method for this:

```
root = tk.Tk() # create a Tk root window
x = -10

...

def mainloop():
    global root
    print ("Starting loop")
    # calls to other root methods must come before call to mainloop().
    root.after(1000, deplaceWindow)
    root.mainloop() # starts the mainloop

def deplaceWindow():
    global root,x
    print (x)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
    x -= 10
    root.after(1000, deplaceWindow)   # 1000 miliseconds

if __name__=="__main__":
    print ("starting mainloop")
    mainloop()
```

---

Additionally: Any interaction with the GUI thread cannot be from other threads (as @Bryan_Oakley explained). You can have a function in your main script which schedules events using the root.after method, but not a direct call from the foreign thread.

Comment: This still doesn't fix the problem. The program never executes the deplaceWindow functon because it is stuck at the root.mainloop() line.

Comment: the root.after(...) call should have been before the root.mainloop() call. The code has been updated.